# How can I set single child element in center align using css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have multiple child element in parent that divided with 3 columns and from 4 element goes to second row with left align:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

li {
  width: 33.33%;
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

But, when I have only a single child in my `<ul>` list, I want single child column into center.

Comment: You can use [`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child).

Comment: But is that possible to set align center using css?

Comment: It depends on your CSS. We really need more information. Please share the accompanying CSS in your question.

Comment: @BenM As I mention in my description, I'm dividing in 3 columns and 4th element goes to next row as left side. But when I have only single li then I want into center.

Comment: But it all depends *how* you're doing that! Columns? Floats? Flexbox?

Comment: I have used flexbox.

Comment: Please demonstrate the issue to make it easier to troubleshoot. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

Since the maximum number per row is 3 you can handle each case alone. You have only 2:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  padding:0;
  margin:5px;
}

li {
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/*1 item */
li:only-child {
  margin:auto;
}
/*2 item */
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-left:auto;
}
li:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(1) {
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS 3 Flexbox to achieve your specific requirement.

```css
ul {
      display: flex;
      width: 150px;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
  </ul>


  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
  </ul>


  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>


  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Thanks Man, But When column goes down it's should be in left side when it's more then 3 or 4 (Whatever column).